# comparing lists of strings

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have two lists of strings like this:

```
list1={"a dog is in the house","have a nice day","hello my friend"};
list2={"a dog is in house","watching tv is nice","hello my friends"};
```

Now i want to use `SmithWatermanSimilarity` to check for similarity like this: For each element in list1 check if there are similar elements in list2 (by defining a threshold value for `SmithWatermanSimilarity` e.g. the value should be higher than 0.9 of `StringLenght` or so)

The desired output should be a list like this:

```
list3={{"a dog is in the house","a dog is in house"},{"have a nice day"},{"hello my friend","hello my friends"}};
```

I already found a rough solution which uses a combination of `If` and two nested `Table` but this seems to me a little bit clumsy one...

```
Table[Table[
  If[SmithWatermanSimilarity[list1[[x]], 
     list2[[y]]] > (StringLength[list1[[x]]]*0.8), {list1[[x]], 
    list2[[y]]}, list1[[x]]], {x, 1, Length[list1]}], {y, 1, 
  Length[list2]}]
```

Comment: @High Performance Mark: See update above. It is not even a rough solution since the desired output is not obtained. How can I efficiently manage to put out EITHER the pair of similar strings OR the string in list1??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t = .9;
{#, Select[list2, Function[x, t StringLength[#] <= SmithWatermanSimilarity[x, #]]]}&/@list1
```

> {{"a dog is in the house", {}},
>   {"have a nice day", {}},
>   {"hello my 
>       friend", {"hello my friends"}}}

```
t = .6;
{#, Select[list2, Function[x, t StringLength[#] <= SmithWatermanSimilarity[x, #]]]}&/@list1
```

> {{"a dog is in the house", {"a dog is in house"}},
>    {"have a nice  day", {}},
>    {"hello my friend", {"hello my friends"}}}

We can use `RelationGraph` to visualize:

```
t = .6;
RelationGraph[t StringLength[#] <= SmithWatermanSimilarity[##] &, list1, list2, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 VertexCoordinates -> Join[MapIndexed[# -> {0, -#2[[1]]/3} &, list1], 
   MapIndexed[# -> {1, -#2[[1]]/3} &, list2]]]
```

[image]

Comment: That is a very nice code but i have another question: what if list1 and list2 are themselves lists of lists? For example {"hello my friend", "DATA Y", "DATA YY"} and {"hello my friends", "DATA Z", "DATA ZZ"}. How do i modify your code to select and match the whole lists based on the first element "hello my friend" / "hello my friends". Or would you suggest, in this case, a different approach? thx.

Comment: @M.A. is  the desired output `{{"hello my friend", "DATA Y", "DATA YY"},{"hello my friends", "DATA Z", "DATA ZZ"}}`  for the example?

Comment: yes. but the matching criterion (SmithWaterman) is only relevant for the first element.

Comment: @M.A. something like: `t = .9; lista = {"hello my friend", "DATA Y", 
  "DATA YY"} ; listb = { {"hello my friends", "DATA Z", 
   "DATA ZZ"}, {"hello my friendsss", "DATA W", "DATA YY"}};
{lista, Select[listb,  t StringLength[#[[1]]] <= 
    SmithWatermanSimilarity[lista[[1]], #[[1]]] &]}`?

Comment: Thats it! I was close to it - i just used a wrong part specification! thx!